# How can I use base64 encoded image to scan for explicit content in Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

According to their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search), `safeSearchDetection` accepts base64 encoded images but when I do that it throws an error:

> **No document found with that ID: Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long**

```
 const visionClient = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
 const data = await visionClient.safeSearchDetection(encoded_img);
 const safeSearchResult = data[0].safeSearchAnnotation;

 if (
    safeSearchResult.adult !== 'VERY_UNLIKELY' ||
    safeSearchResult.spoof !== 'VERY_UNLIKELY' ||
    safeSearchResult.medical !== 'VERY_UNLIKELY' ||
    safeSearchResult.violence !== 'VERY_UNLIKELY' ||
    safeSearchResult.racy !== 'VERY_UNLIKELY'
 ) {
    functions.logger.log('Offensive image found.');
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here that I cant see?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/vision.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869),

> If the key (first param in `safeSearchDetection`) is `content` (`base64` string in this case), the value should be a `Buffer`.

```
const imgBuffer = Buffer.from(encoded_img, "base64");

const data = await visionClient.safeSearchDetection(imgBuffer);
```